# AngularJS - how to iterate array on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm

I have an array and I want to be able to go to the next index of the array whenever I click a button.

Html code where I call the function:

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="date-switcher">
    <header>                    
      <h1>{{ ctrl.percent}}</h1>
    </header>
  </div>

  <div class="arrows-switch">              
    <div class="right-arrow" ng-click="nextValue()">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/images/images/arrow-sprite_02.png">. 
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jvs code where I try to iterate :

```
var ctrl = this;

var percent = [
    { value: 70,},
    { value: 93,},
    { value: 100,},
    { value: 94,},
    { value: 66,}
];

for(var i=0; i < percent.length;i++) {
    
    ctrl.percent = percent[i].value
    break
}

$scope.nextValue = function() {

    ctrl.percent = percent[i+1].value
}
```

The output from header h1 `{{ctrl.percent}}` is 70 which is the `ctrl.percent` first array item, but when I call the function `nextValue`, it goes to the second array item and stops.

How can I make it keep going to the next array item till the last?

Expected:
1st click - 2nd array item
2nd click 3rd array item
etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
indexValue = 0;
$scope.nextValue = function() {
    this.percent = percent[indexValue+1].value
  }
```

Declare the index value as a global variable. I think this should do the trick.